# Pulling Featured BigCommerce Products into Separate Site

Tags: bigcommerce

We have a website that's built in Drupal 7 and the site's store is being handled via BigCommerce.

With the BigCommerce API, would it be possible to pull in featured products to display in a sidebar on the Drupal site? At most it'd be the product title, image, price, and then it would link over to the full product page on BigCommmerce.

Answer (score 1):

Not the "best" way, but can be done in 10 minutes... Write some AJAX to grab the featured products HTML from your BigCommerce site and insert them on your Drupal site's sidebar.

Clone this [node proxy](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) repo and host your own version on [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) for free in 5 minutes... This will allow you to make [cross origin requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) using AJAX and pull in the div or divs you need on your Drupal site in a short time. Seems like overkill to me to fetch from BC API for such a small feature.

**Code**

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
    if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
        options.url = 'YOUR OWN HOSTED PROXY APP URL HERE' + options.url;
    }
});
$.get(
    'BC PAGE URL HERE',
    function (response) {
        MANIPULATE DOM HERE WITH RESPONSE DATA
        $('.home-list').html($(response).find('#content').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bigcommerce supplies RSS / ATOM feeds for "Featured products" (and many more)

From [Bigcommerce support](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Syndication-Feeds):

LATEST 10 FEATURED PRODUCTS:

- http://myawesomestore.com/rss.php?action=featuredproducts&type=rss
  (RSS)

Comment: rss.php is no longer available.